# Drupal users taking a long time to delete

Tags: users

I am having trouble deleting users (mainly bots) from my Drupal site. When I go through the process to even delete **one user** it takes SO long, and eventually times out. This was not the case a couple months ago. Would this be something to do with my hosting company, or site related? I have the bulk operations module and various other ones, but this is happening even if I go into user management and just delete one selected user.

Any ideas will help!

Thanks!

Comment: I have three environments (dev, stage, prod). The Dev environment runs perfectly. Stage and Prod are very slow. Stage and Prod do match so its probably something in there.

Comment: Given the symptoms, my guess is there's some service timing out. Difficult to say exactly what without knowing what modules you have installed. Do you have any that integrate with external services, such as Mollom? Your hosting might have changed firewall rules, hence the change of behaviour.

Comment: Is the users content being deleted too? Do the users has a lot of content?

Comment: if a script times out it's not going to be able to provide you with any useful error reporting.  you should take a look at your server's error log file and see what message the server provides when it times out.  that will help you (and us) narrow down the issue.